# Can I use a different DB with my Magento 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2.3, database, data-migration

I have done some work on a site, basically theme, graphics, content and such.  I want to keep that work without losing it but I need to use a different database.   The current one got corrupted when Cart2Cart did a migration from M 1.9 to M 2.3.5.  I didn't catch the errors at first. Their solution was to redo the migration on a new Magento site (long story).   Basically we weren't able to open past orders.  The new database works fine, but I am trying to prevent a lot of rework if possible.  Can I just update/change where the database is?  I know in M1 I could do that but I don't know if M2 is different.  They will share the same server..

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what database you intend to use? And did you try using the Magento data migration tool when you migrated?